# KML / Google Map - Specifying the zoom level of an embeded map in an iFrame

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have the following kml file that I am loading in Google map, it's locating the pointer correctly however the it's always zoomed at the maximum level.

Using the google map APIs I can set my own zoom level but I am trying to do this using an embedded map in an iFrame (provided by google).

Are there anyways to set the zoom level in the kml itself? I had a look at LookAt and the Camera attribute but the doc say they aren't supported in Google Map.

Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">  
        <Placemark>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>144.897426,-37.8045</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </kml>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control Google Map's display behaviour by the arguments you pass in the src of the iframe element - in your case by setting the "z" parameter - see [here](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters)

simply make your iframe source as "http://maps.google.com/?ll=48.064372,16.348977&z=10" and change z=10 to any other higher (up to 20) or lower value (down to 0)

Alternatively, in the Maps API you would use the [setCenter()](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.setCenter) function to set the zoom level

Comment: Thanks for that! tested and confirmed.  I was looking WAY to deep for my solution.  Nice resource you linked, I'll keep it in my bookmark.

Have a great day.