# how to control zooming out in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

how to control zooming out in google maps.
I just need no zooming out

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? You mean you want to define a maximum zoom level beyond which a user shouldn't be able to zoom out?

Comment: yes even that is fine. what u are saying. maximum zoom level beyong which user should not zoom out

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the [google maps api chapter zoomlevels](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Zoomlevels), the maximum zoom in is 22. So you should add to the static image url `&zoom=22` so the final url would look something like:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.997672&zoom=22&size=800x800&sensor=false

Comment: this does not help , as my is not a static map. but it reads kml files

Comment: "kml zoom level" search first result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690129/kml-google-map-specifying-the-zoom-level-of-an-embeded-map-in-an-iframe

Comment: i read that link it does not help me it seems...can u help me. my map is http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF&msa=0&msid=103305490589617981660.00049015211c020521921

Comment: u can access my map using link below. http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF&msa=0&msid=103305490589617981660.00049015211c020521921  .

Comment: sorry for that i tried &z=100 in achor but it still allow zooming out.

Comment: i want to stop zooming out after certain limit  . i tried with iframe and wanted to stop zooming out after certain limit