# Zoom Level in KML File

Tags: google-maps, kml

The KML file is loading correctly (i.e. I can see the marker correctly), however what I wanted is to see map to be more "zoomed out" upon load. How will I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this page:
[KML / Google Map - Specifying the zoom level of an embeded map in an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690129/kml-google-map-specifying-the-zoom-level-of-an-embeded-map-in-an-iframe)

The answer is from MikeD:

> "You can control Google Map's display behaviour by the arguments you
>   pass in the src of the iframe element - in your case by setting the
>   "z" parameter - see here
>
> simply make your iframe source as
>   "http://maps.google.com/?ll=48.064372,16.348977&z=10" and change z=10
>   to any other higher (up to 20) or lower value (down to 0)
>
> Alternatively, in the Maps API you would use the setCenter() function
>   to set the zoom level"

Hope this is help you !

Comment: Well, i'm not sure that you can do it in the KML file...
take a look at the documentation: http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps.html

Comment: but the link that you gave does not include the zooming function. But anyway, thanks for the time.. i hope somebody can be able to help me

Comment: Brandon: Did you find this link: ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187837/google-maps-zoom-gets-over-riden-when-using-a-kml-file

Comment: yes and i already got the answer.. it think it is natural/automatic for the maps to be displayed to be zoomed in/out as to cover all the areas of the markers.. so the farther the markers get, the more zoomed out the map is. thanks!